Can you extract Stored Procedures from a .mdf file without attaching it or third party tools?
I got a 120 GB .mdf file. It should contain a stored procedure which was only for a prototype, and thus was removed when we patched the db with new procedures.
I would like to recover it, but I can't attach the db to my local db, as I do not have a license for it. When I try to attach it to the server, it will complain about a db already exists with that name and I do not want to detach the server as it is currently being used.
Is there a way I can use some cmd command, or equal, to extract the SQL script from the file?

well no
There's no native way to extract a single stored procedure from a backup (.bak) or dangling data file (.mdf). There may be 3rd party utilities that would allow you to do that, but I don't have any experience with them and referring you to one would be inappropriate on this forum.
You won't be able to attach a 120GB database to an instance of SQL Server Express Edition, but you can download SQL Server Developer Edition and install it for free to bypass that limitation. It doesn't matter for any practical reason if you use the SQL Server 2022 version here, since you only need it for this singular purpose.
Once it's installed, you can run this. I'm working under the assumption that you don't also have a log (.ldf) file to go along with it:
CREATE DATABASE 
    [YourDatabase_copy] 
ON 
(
    NAME = YourDatabase_Copy,
    FILENAME = 'C:\YourDatabase.mdf'
) 
FOR 
    ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;

If you do have a log file, you'll want to reference it in the CREATE DATABASE command like this:
CREATE DATABASE 
    [YourDatabase_copy] 
ON 
(
    NAME = YourDatabase_Copy,
    FILENAME = 'C:\YourDatabase.mdf'
) 
LOG ON
( 
    NAME = YourDatabase_Copy_log,
    FILENAME = 'C:\YourDatabase.ldf'
);

